# Wordpress data as JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

The code below is used to print out some data on products from Woocommerce on my Wordpress website.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 200,
                'product_cat' =>'pants'
            );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product; 


    echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().' '.the_title(). ' '.the_content().' '.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true).' '.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true).'</a>';
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This gets data that I need on products such as their name, image, reg. price and sale price etc. This code does this successfully and echoes the data onto the page. The code returns this data on each product, so that a list of products with their name, image etc. is printed onto the html page.

However I need to get the same data that this code retrieves, but in JSON format.

Many products would be returned with each as a JSON object in this format:

```
[{"term_id":"64","name":"Argentina","slug":"argentina","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"64","taxonomy":"product_cat","description":"","parent":"13","count":"20","meta_id":"154","woocommerce_term_id":"64","meta_key":"order","meta_value":"0","cat_ID":"64","category_count":"20","category_description":"","cat_name":"Argentina","category_nicename":"argentina","category_parent":"13"},]
```

The JSON above is returned when I do this `echo json_encode($loop->get_posts());`

How do I get the same data that is echoed onto the page returned in JSON rather than as HTML.

Please help on this. I have been looking for an answer for this for a while.

Is it just impossible? No one seems to have the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

When I do `echo json_encode($loop);`, I get the following:

```
{"query_vars":{"post_type":"product","posts_per_page":200,"product_cat":"Alcopops","error":"","m":0,"p":0,"post_parent":"","subpost":"","subpost_id":"","attachment":"","attachment_id":0,"name":"","static":"","pagename":"","page_id":0,"second":"","minute":"","hour":"","day":0,"monthnum":0,"year":0,"w":0,"category_name":"","tag":"","cat":"","tag_id":"","author_name":"","feed":"","tb":"","paged":0,"comments_popup":"","meta_key":"","meta_value":"","preview":"","s":"","sentence":"","fields":"","menu_order":"","category__in":[],"category__not_in":[],"category__and":[],"post__in":[],"post__not_in":[],"tag__in":[],"tag__not_in":[],"tag__and":[],"tag_slug__in":[],"tag_slug__and":[],"post_parent__in":[],"post_parent__not_in":[],"ignore_sticky_posts":false,"suppress_filters":false,"cache_results":true,"update_post_term_cache":true,"update_post_meta_cache":true,"nopaging":false,"comments_per_page":"50","no_found_rows":false,"taxonomy":"product_cat","term":"Alcopops","order":"DESC"},"tax_query":{"queries":[{"taxonomy":"product_cat","terms":["Alcopops"],"include_children":true,"field":"slug","operator":"IN"}],"relation":"AND"},"meta_query":{"queries":[],"relation":null},"post_count":3,"current_post":-1,"in_the_loop":false,"comment_count":0,"current_comment":-1,"found_posts":"3","max_num_pages":1,"max_num_comment_pages":0,"is_single":false,"is_preview":false,"is_page":false,"is_archive":true,"is_date":false,"is_year":false,"is_month":false,"is_day":false,"is_time":false,"is_author":false,"is_category":false,"is_tag":false,"is_tax":true,"is_search":false,"is_feed":false,"is_comment_feed":false,"is_trackback":false,"is_home":false,"is_404":false,"is_comments_popup":false,"is_paged":false,"is_admin":false,"is_attachment":false,"is_singular":false,"is_robots":false,"is_posts_page":false,"is_post_type_archive":true,"query_vars_hash":"5bcaf536a84f30a7d5cd599078fa354d","query_vars_changed":false,"thumbnails_cached":false,"query":{"post_type":"product","posts_per_page":200,"product_cat":"Alcopops"},"request":"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (26) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 200","posts":[{"ID":254,"post_author":"3","post_date":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_date_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_content":"","post_title":"Green Sands","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"green-sands-2","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_modified_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/cbbnideas.com\/brydens-website\/?post_type=product&p=254","menu_order":0,"post_type":"product","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw","format_content":null},{"ID":246,"post_author":"3","post_date":"2013-10-17 23:15:41","post_date_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:15:41","post_content":"Ginger Shandy is an exciting blend of the natural ginger root extract and beer. It has a crisp ginger taste that is carefully balanced with a slight, sweet note and beer flavour without any after taste.\r\nTaste - clean, ginger flavour\r\nAroma - ginger aroma\r\nVisual - clear, golden colour","post_title":"Carib Shandy Ginger","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"carib-shandy-ginger-2","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2013-10-17 23:25:47","post_modified_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:25:47","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/cbbnideas.com\/brydens-website\/?post_type=product&p=246","menu_order":0,"post_type":"product","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw","format_content":null},{"ID":43,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2013-09-27 13:50:21","post_date_gmt":"2013-09-27 13:50:21","post_content":"Sorrel Shandy is a blend of sorrel extract and beer. Its flavour can be described as a pleasant, sweet, smooth, refreshing sorrel flavour, carefully balanced sweet note and beer flavour.\u00a0Taste - clean, sorrel flavour.\u00a0Aroma - slightly sweet, floral aroma.","post_title":"Carib Shandy Sorrel","post_excerpt":"Sorrel Shandy is a blend of sorrel extract and beer. Its flavour can be described as a pleasant, sweet, smooth, refreshing sorrel flavour, carefully balanced sweet note and beer flavour.","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"carib-shandy-sorrel-3","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2013-10-14 19:52:28","post_modified_gmt":"2013-10-14 19:52:28","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/cbbnideas.com\/brydens-website\/?post_type=product&p=43","menu_order":0,"post_type":"product","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw","format_content":null}],"post":{"ID":254,"post_author":"3","post_date":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_date_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_content":"","post_title":"Green Sands","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"open","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"green-sands-2","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_modified_gmt":"2013-10-17 23:24:19","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/cbbnideas.com\/brydens-website\/?post_type=product&p=254","menu_order":0,"post_type":"product","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw","format_content":null}}
```

Comment: perhaps instead of echoing inside the loop, you assigned the `get_whatever()` versions of those calls to a php arra, then encode the array...

Comment: What assists on the screen when you echo out the json encode part? Have you tried just using `echo json_encode($loop);` ?

Comment: @Howlin Please see the edit above.

Comment: @MarcB Not following really. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Do you need both a page the prints out JSON and one that prints HTML data?

Comment: Marc B's solution should work though. You just have to make sure to not render theme template stuff and set correct headers.

Comment: @Gohn67 I just need the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code starting from while loop to end with this

```
$jsondata = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
global $product; 

$jsondata[] = array(
    'image' =>woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(),
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content(),
    'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
    'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true)
);
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();

ob_clean();
echo json_encode($jsondata);
exit();
```

Comment: Tried this but `title` and `content` show up as value "null" `"title":null,"content":null`. However, the sale price and regular price values show up.

Comment: The title and content show up at the top of the page but not in the JSON

Comment: sorry.. use get_the_title() instead of the_title()

Comment: and get_the_content() instead of the_content() .. the_title() and the_content() echoes its values while get_.. versions return them

Comment: Also, do you know of a way to replace `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(),` with getting the actual product image url. And including this as the value for `image` in the array?

Comment: I did not use that plugin so I really don't know. What is it returning and what do you want it to return? Give examples, maybe I can help

Comment: Well when I use the thumbnail it just returns and empty image block. As in an image that can't be displayed. I want `image: "www.image.com/mywp.jpg"` to be returned in the json. So that I can reference the `image` key to get the product image. (I am alos not very familiar with the plugin)

Comment: Hmm, I don,t know. I searched on web, maybe this function will help: woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() put that instead of the ..thumbnail() function ..

Comment: Nevermind the suggestion above, i think it will just return a dummy image.. Search for a function that will return the image path

Comment: use this.. get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size) use 'shop_catalog' or 'thumbnail' or 'medium' 'large' 'full' etc, i think they return links for images with different sizes

Comment: Looking into it. Thanks, will post when I get it working